# Jupyter Connection Issues

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[image: blinking connected]

Jupyter notebook is blinking "Connected" while the Python 3 kernel says "no connection."

I have tried starting from another port used in the terminal:

```
jupyter notebook --port 8889
```

The terminal returns the following error:

[image: terminal error]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to downgrade tornado, this worked for me.

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

based on: https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/issues/689